# pg_restore ERROR: "Relation does not exist" and creating new database

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump, pg-restore, exists

I have made a backup of my specific tables that I want to restore into a new database using:

```
call pg_dump -Fc -h server -d database -U user -p password -v -f dump.sql -t public.table1 -t public.table2
```

And I have no problems.

I then want to restore the dump by creating a new database with pg_restore using:

```
call pg_restore --clean --create -d temp -h server -p password -U user dump.sql
```

This gives me a "database temp does not exist" error. This should have created the database and restored it as far as I understand.

I However then create the "temp" database manually and run:

```
call pg_restore --clean --create -d temp -h server -p password -U user dump.sql
```

This follows through, but does not create the tables and gives me an error "`relation table1`" and "`relation table2`" does not exist and only creates the corresponding id_sewuences for the two tables.

What I actually want is to not have to manually create the new database and that all tables in the backup is restored into a brand new database via pg_restore using:

```
call pg_restore --clean --create -d temp -h server -p password -U user dump.sql
```

as I understand it.

Please Help, very frustrating

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `--create` and `-d` are used together, the argument to `-d` is **not** the name of the database to create, it's the name of an existing database to connect to run the `CREATE DATABASE` statement, because it's impossible to create a database if you're not already connect to another database.

This is [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) as:

> When this option is used, the database named with -d is used only to
>   issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data
>   is restored into the database name that appears in the archive.

This is why `pg_restore` errors out with *database temp does not exist*

You should add a `createdb` step in your restore procedure since you want to create a specific database name anyway, not one that comes from the backup.

For the second problem, it's a completely different question, hard to guess why it happens without complete error messages.

Also note that `-p` is not followed by a password but by a port number.